# Changing compiler before AC_CHECK_HEADER doesn't changing Preprocessor

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf

I'm writing a `configure.ac` script for a library which has a few dependencies.  One of the dependencies is a library which requires MPI.

I'm using a [macro](http://ac-archive.sourceforge.net/ac-archive/acx_mpi.m4) to detect the availability of MPI and use it's variable definitions to change the C++ compiler to the associated MPI wrapper. Unfortunately, this is not reflected completely when I perform an `AC_CHECK_HEADER`; the compiler test works fine, but the preprocessor test fails.

failure in `config.log` (notice the preprocessor test uses `g++` instead of `mpic++`):

```
configure:17591: checking for mpic++
configure:17607: found /opt/apps/gcc4_7/mvapich2-x/2.0.0/bin/mpic++
configure:17618: result: mpic++
configure:17636: checking for MPI_Init
configure:17636: mpic++ -o conftest -g -O2 -std=c++11 conftest.cpp >&5
configure:17636: $? = 0
configure:17636: result: yes
configure:17729: checking for mpi.h
configure:17742: mpic++ -c -g -O2 conftest.cpp >&5
configure:17742: $? = 0
configure:17743: result: yes
configure:17781: checking mylibrary.h usability
configure:17781: mpic++ -c -g -O2 -I./mylibrary/include -std=c++11 conftest.cpp >&5
configure:17781: $? = 0
configure:17781: result: yes
configure:17781: checking mylibrary.h presence
configure:17781: g++ -E -I./mylibrary/include -std=c++11 conftest.cpp
In file included from ./mylibrary/include/mylibrary.h:4,
                 from conftest.cpp:26:
./mylibrary/include/mylibrary.h:4:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
```

`configure.ac` associated section:

```
...
ACX_MPI([], [AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find an MPI C++ compiler wrapper.])])
CXX="$MPICXX"
LIBS="$MPILIBS $LIBS"
CPPFLAGS="-I$with_mylibrary_path/include $CPPFLAGS"

AC_CHECK_HEADER([mylibrary.h], [], [works=no]
...
```

Now the configure only throws a warning, and proceeds with the compiler's results, but I'm pedantic and want to solve this issue so that my users don't think it's an issue with their system, build setup, etc.

I've looked around, and haven't found a way to reset the preprocessor command for this to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: You going to have to take a deep breath, and figure out what's going on by looking at the robo-generated configure script, and what exact command is getting executed, what exact command SHOULD be getting executed, and why it's not doing that. There have been similarly haired situations in the past when I had no other options, but to dig into the configure script, and figure out what really goes on under the covers.

Comment: I was afraid I might have to do that.  I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try taking the advice of the authors of `ACX_MPI` and use `AC_TRY_COMPILE` instead...

```
dnl We have to use AC_TRY_COMPILE and not AC_CHECK_HEADER because the
dnl latter uses $CPP, not $CC (which may be mpicc).
```

BTW The [`AX_MPI`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_mpi.html) macro seems to be a more updated (but not that different) version of `ACX_MPI`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `CXXCPP` is used as the command to run the C++ preprocessor compiler ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.66/html_node/C_002b_002b-Compiler.html)), so I modified my configure script:

```
...
ACX_MPI([], [AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find an MPI C++ compiler wrapper.])])
CXX="$MPICXX"
CXXCPP="$CXX -E"
LIBS="$MPILIBS $LIBS"
CPPFLAGS="-I$with_mylibrary_path/include $CPPFLAGS"

AC_CHECK_HEADER([mylibrary.h], [], [works=no]
...
```

and the warning is gone.